# Controlling vertical alignment of wrapped inline-block or float divs

Tags: html, css-float, css

Please have a look at [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQkcd/2/), that illustrates my problem. 
Stretch the 'result' window to the left, and see the vertical gaps between the top 'grid3' row and the bottom one.

The goal is to have **no vertical gaps** between divs what so ever. All DIVs should stick to the top of the divs above them. (That's why this 'grid' layout was tried at the first place, but as you can see it doesn't solve the problem in 100%).

**Conditions**:

1. Each div has a fixed width, but an unknown arbitrary height.
2. The container DIV's width **doesn't have to** be 'auto', but it's preferred. This **still also happens** when giving it a fixed width though.
3. All DIVs must be horizontally aligned to the left.
4. If still using this 'grid approach', the number of divs inside each 'grid' must be finite.

The same problem also happens if using floating (float:left) divs instead, 
see: http://jsfiddle.net/pQkcd/3/ (stretch result window to the left).

Thanks.

Comment: If accept using javascript to solve it, [this jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) should be helpful.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that plugin. Sites like pinterest are using something similar which positions the elements absolutely on the screen dynamically.

Comment: it looks promising, I will check it out. But of-course if there is a possibility of a pure-css solution it will be preferable :).
By the way, will this plugin work correctly if the container's width is set to 'auto'?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this neat JQuery solution, which can deal with a container of an unknown width (width:auto). This works with DIVs having 'float:left' and 'position:relative'. I'm referring to each of these DIVs as a "panel" (Each will also have a 'panel' class).

The trick is to figure out how many panels are there in each row (you don't know that in advance, since the width of the container is uknown at first). You can figure out the number of panels per row by tracking the first change in position().top. The panels in the first row should all start in top:0. 
Once you know how many panels per row - you can readjust the panels in the nonfirst rows according to the position of each panel directly above it, and you also can & need to set the first panel of each new row to "clear:left".

This needs to be run after the panels are already in the DOM. You can also attach it to the 
$(window).resize event - so that it will readjust the panels when the size of the container changes.

```
function fixPanelsPosition() {
    var panelsPassedInRow = 0;
    var panelsPerRow = 0;
    var $panelAbove;
    var newTop;
    var ptop;
    $('.panel').each(function (i) {
        // reset css (because this will be called on window resize as well...)
        $(this).css('top','').css('clear','');
        panelsPassedInRow++;
        ptop = $(this).position().top;
        //Figure out number of panels per row:
        if (ptop == 0) { panelsPerRow++; }
        // new row
        if (panelsPassedInRow > panelsPerRow) {
            //First panel in each row should have 'clear:left':
            $(this).css('clear','left');
            panelsPassedInRow = 1;
        }
        // If not in first row - bump panel up:
        if (ptop > 0) {
            $panelAbove = $('.panel').eq(i-panelsPerRow);
            newTop = $panelAbove.position().top + $panelAbove.height();
           /*  Bump the panel up by setting its 'top' value to a negative value.
            *  If you have margin-top/margin-bottom on the panels you should add that 
            *  value to the calculation:
            */
            $(this).css('top',-($(this).position().top-newTop));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can also readjust position after each separate new append of a panel. You check its 'top' - if it's 0, you increase the perrow counter, if it's not 0 - then you already have the perrow, and you can do the readjustment. To check if its a 'first-in-a-row' panel, you can test panelindex%perrow for 0...
tried and tested :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a (floated left) container for every column is not an option?